# how to copy or move all files and directory to the other user via terminal command

Tags: command-line, files, users, filemanager, user-management

I have list of directory and file to my current **user** which is the user1

and i want it to copy or transfer it to the other **jay** which is user2?

Im using a Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command between two users only possible by the root user.

```
          su root
              (or)
           sudo su
```

We can copy the files between two users by the following command.

```
     cp /home/user1/location_of_the_files /home/user2/location_to_paste_file
```

We can move the files between two users by the following command.

```
     mv /home/user1/location_of_the_files /home/user2/location_to_paste_file
```

Comment: Probably, OP wants to use `chown -r user2: /home/user2/location_to_paste_file` in the end.

Comment: So that i login into the root user to move or copy from different users.

Comment: You can also use `sudo` directly instead ...

Comment: Yes you are correct. But if you are not a sudo user what should you do?

Comment: Please see my answer, now it should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not a `sudo` user (or have no access to the `root` user), but know the passwords for both users:

Prerequisites:

`/home/user1/` needs `o+rx` permissions (this is the default), otherwise change it using `chmod o+rx /home/user1/` or use `/tmp` instead if you don't want that.

```bsh
# As user1, mv or cp to your home dir (alternative /tmp):
mv /home/user1/path/to/location_of_the_files /home/user1/
# Give user2 access to read files and read and access directories
setfacl -R -m u:user2:rX /home/user1/location_of_the_files
# Login as user2
su user2
cp -r /home/user1/location_of_the_files ~/

# Back to user1:
#   delete the directory if you wanted it moved
#   or move it back to the original location and remove the facl using:
setfacl -Rbn /home/user1/location_of_the_files
```

---

Much easier If you have an SSH Server installed and enabled:

```bsh
# As user2
scp -r user1@localhost:/home/user1/path/to/location_of_the_files/ ~/
```

Comment: Hope you get the idea how it works. It would be easier with a clear example with specific locations and only one of copy or move.